# Extra code in the beginning of all frames

Tags: beamer

I want to add at the beginning of all `beamer` `frame` environments some extra commands (for example, `\vspace{-0.5cm}`) and my trial with

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frame begin}{}{\vspace{-0.5cm}}
```

doesn't work at all.

Which line should I add to solve this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I do not know if this breaks some thing some where!</sub>

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\vspace*{-1in}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Some text
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```