# Add command at the beginning of all frames

Tags: beamer, etoolbox, patching, hooks

I need to add a command `\setRTL` from the [`bidi` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) to write right-to-left text, at the beginning of  every frame.

[Another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185721/54817) does not solve the issue; any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{etoolbox}  % no longer needed; loaded by Beamer from v3.36

\usepackage{bidi}

\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setRTL}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{frame title}
        hello world

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item first item
            \item second item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226319, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7126, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7427

Comment: Also relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9136

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot directly hook into the `begin` of Beamer's `frame` environment with the usual [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) `\AtBeginEnvironment`, as [hinted at elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226351/134641).

Replacing your `\AtBeginEnvironment` with `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`, is actually sufficient. That is:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setRTL}
```

This may, however, have undesirable side-effects, since it hooks in prior to the environment's definition.

One alternative is the following (hooking into [`@checkframetitle`](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/28ce6329603eb41b748672780cfdc9e4b0952a85/base/beamerbaseframe.sty#L116)), adapted from [another similar answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7430/134641), however it will not affect the slide's title:

```
\makeatletter
    \pretocmd\beamer@checkframetitle{\setRTL}
\makeatother
```

Finally, you could instead hook into the [earlier `@framenotesbegin`](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/28ce6329603eb41b748672780cfdc9e4b0952a85/base/beamerbaseframe.sty#L88), which would affect the slide title (obtaining an equivalent result to the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` approach):

```
\makeatletter
    \pretocmd\beamer@framenotesbegin{\setRTL}
\makeatother
```