# Beamer - Floating Frame Title

Tags: beamer, positioning, frame-title

Beamer frame title is placed on the top of the slide by default. Is there any way to place it just above the content in each slide ?

[image]

[image]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
The new arrangment
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fake such a frametitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\floattitle}[1]{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
     \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
     \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
     \strut#1\strut\par%
     \vskip-1ex%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\floattitle{Frame Title}
The new arrangment
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sam, but this requires the \floattile to be repeated within each frame, even if the all the frames have the same title (say "heading"). Whereas, in the case of a floating frame title (if it is possible) the title (here "heading") is to be given at once, in the preamble.

Comment: @Ashok If you want to add it to every frame: `\makeatletter
    \pretocmd\beamer@checkframetitle{\floattitle{Frame title}}
\makeatother`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436338/36296 for more information